# Problem with Synchronous query execution in cassandra-driver (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, cassandra, synchronous, cassandra-driver, datastax-node-driver

I'm trying to create at runtime keyspaces and tables inside them using `cassandra-driver` node implementation maintained by datastax.

On the documentation ([here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/devapp/doc/devapp/driversSyncAsync.html)) it's pointed out that there is a sync-way to call the `execute()` method that should block the execution until the the result from the query is returned.

I think that examples (both for sync and async section for Node.js) linked at this [url](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.4/features/promise-callback/) are only for async execution, because they didn't block until result is returned.

I'm missing something or is not possible to achieve a synchronous execution of a query with Node.js driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js libraries that use I/O are generally async only. That's the case for all/most DB drivers.

Given how [Node.js event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) works, sync execution is usually not what you want.

If you want a syntax that is as comfortable to synchronous execution in Node.js, you should use [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```js
async function doSomething(client) {
  await client.execute(query1);
  // ...
  await client.execute(query2);
  await client.execute(query3);
}
```

Comment: It turns out that I've done a mess with Promises and async/await. Thanks for the crystal clear response, helped a lot!